# Python - remove files + mysql

Tags: python, mysql, file

I need to delete all files (that are not mine) from a folder. My script is in C:\Python22

3 files are mine: **MY_PROGRAM.dll** , **IM_A_TEXT.txt** , **STACKOVERFLOW.DAT**

I want to delete all the files in the directory EXCEPT my 3 files.

If a file has OSError on delete, I want to send the name of the file to a mysql table.

I think first we must to define my 3 files so:

**my_file1** = "MY_PROGRAM.dll"

**my_file2** = "IM_A_TEXT.txt"

**my_file3** = "STACKOVERFLOW.DAT"

Then we must make a list ( an array ? ) of the files that are not mine:

import os

files_only = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir( os.curdir ))

if files_only != **my_file1** or files_only != **my_file2** or files_only != **my_file3**:

```
try:
    os.remove(files_only[*.*])
except OSError:
    import MySQLdb, string
    import time
    mi_nombre = "Maria"
    mode_check_FI = "ARCHIVOS"
    tiempo = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    FILE_1 = files_only[0]
    FILE_2 = files_only[1]
    FILE_3 = files_only[3]
    FILE_4 = files_only[4]
    FILE_5 = files_only[5]
    mysql = MySQLdb.connect(IP, "USER", "PASSSWORD", "DB_NAME")
    cursor = mysql.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute ("""INSERT INTO info (jugador, type_check, actual_time, FILE_1, FILE_2, FILE_3, FILE_4, FILE_5) values (%s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s)""", (mi_nombre, mode_check_FI, tiempo, FILE1, FILE_2, FILE_3, FILE_4, FILE_5))
        mysql.commit()
        mysql.close()
    except MySQL.Error:
        pass
pass
```

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

Python part is solved by:

```
files_only = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir( os.curdir ))
    my_files = ['MY_PROGRAM.dll', 'IM_A_TEXT.txt', 'STACKOVERFLOW.DAT'] 
    for file in files_only:
        if file not in my_files:
            code..
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood, I can offer the following suggestions.

```
if files_only != my_file1 or files_only != my_file2 or files_only != my_file3:
```

The above line is not pythonic. Moreover, comparing a list to a string will not produce the desired result. Use of `set()` makes it simple:

```
my_files = {"MY_PROGRAM.dll", "IM_A_TEXT.txt", "STACKOVERFLOW.DAT"}
files_only = set(filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir( os.curdir )))
for file in files_only - my_files:
    your code
```

Comment: my_files = {"MY_PROGRAM.dll", "IM_A_TEXT.txt", "STACKOVERFLOW.DAT"} RESULT: SyntaxError: invalid syntax 

my_files = ['MY_PROGRAM.dll', 'IM_A_TEXT.txt', 'STACKOVERFLOW.DAT'] RESULT: global name 'set' is not defined

The "set" class was introduced in Python 2.4 and i'm using 2.2 :(

Comment: I am using Python 3. Sorry about that.